# Do I scale remote image per MDPI or per XXHDPI?

Tags: android-layout, image-scaling

I am fetching images remotely and need to apply scaling so they look nice on all devices. But I am not sure what DPI value shall I take as a reference point.

For example, the size of the remote image is 155px which looks nice on `XXHDPI` devices. I need to scale it for devices of lower DPI.

So in this case, does scale 1 means `MDPI` or `XXHDPI`?

Comment: `1 means MDPI or XXHDPI` has not a lot of sense. keep in mind the correct proportions: 0.75 for ldpi, 1 for mdpi, ... 3 for xxhdpi. So, 155px at xxhdpi means 155px is 3 times the mdpi resolution (which should be then scaled down to 155px / 3 ~ 52px for the mdpi version of your image)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I am aware of that scale. So if image looks good on XXHDPI, then I can rely that scale=3. This is what I wanted to know as I did not know if I can apply their scaling the way you showed. Thanks. PS. you can make a better reply if you want for others (maybe with less knowledge) and I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: OK... I entered the details, to the limits of logorrea... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1 means MDPI or XXHDPI` has not a lot of sense. mdpi is **always to be considered **the unity**, so to speak.
Keep in mind the correct proportions:

- 0.75 for ldpi
- 1 for mdpi
- 1.5 fot hdpi
- 2 for xhdpi
- 3 for xxhdpi

So, 155px at xxhdpi means 155px is 3 times the mdpi resolution.
This means that the correct px size for the mdpi resolution will be 155px / 3 (~ 52px).

To get the hdpi version, you'd do 155px / 2 (~ 78px). (I simplified here, it was (155px / 3) * 1.5.
To get the xhdpi version... (155px / 3) * 2 (~ 104px).

155 / 3 is the magic number to get the **unity** (mdpi version)

So, to get the ldpi version, do (155px / 3) * 0.75 (~ 39px) (or you can simplify to 155px / 4).

Note that you could use **multiplication for the inverse** to get a **faster division**: 
`155 / 3` is **slower** than `155 * 0.333` - This is a `golden rule` for every CPU/ALU.